# How to compile and run Java with jar and txt-files from Terminal

Tags: java, jar, terminal, compiler-errors

I have a project, which has following structure

[image]

If I run it from IDE everything is OK, but I can't run it from terminal.

To compile I tried from Task_3

```
javac -cp lib/*.jar src/*.java
```

and it works, but I don't get it to run

if I try

```
cd src

java -cp .:jsoup-1.11.3.jar Main
```

it gives me an error **Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/out.txt (No such file or directory)**

My code with this txt.out is in the Writer Class and looks like:

```
 String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");

 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src"+ fs + "out.txt");
```

I tried to change path to './out.txt', it compiles in terminal, but then it writes nothings to the file out.txt. Also I get the error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup**, when I try to run after compilation...
I really stuck and i would appreciate any help!

Comment: Why do you have `.class` and `.txt` files in `src` folder?

Comment: Well, if you're running from inside the `src` folder, then that file is just `out.txt`, not `src/out.txt`.  You could run it from the folder above, but you'd need to change the class path accordingly.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I moved the txt files in separate directory on the level of src ( i will update my question and image now). The I try to run from folder Task_3 the command java -cp .:jsoup-1.11.3.jar Main , but it says Could not find or load main class Main, and if try src/Main it doesn't help too...

Comment: Put `src` in your classpath, if that's where `Main.class` is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. I would REALLY suggest using Maven for something like this. I know it might be too much, but it's worth it. Maven is definitely a standard and it makes everything much easier. :)

### 1. Mavenize your project

RMB on your project and select **Add Framework Support...**

[image]

and then select **Maven** from the list, and apply.

You have now a new `pom.xml` file. Enter it.
Change your `artifactId` and `groupId` accordingly.

Apply proper plugins next:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- That allows you to shade your libraries to your jar !-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- That plugin compiles your jar with Java 8 !-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- That plugin adds a manifest and makes your jar file !-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>  YOUR MAIN CLASS  </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- This allow Maven to filter your resources folder! !-->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

(just copy and paste that)
Remember! You need to change `YOUR MAIN CLASS` to your proper main class where your `main(String[] args)` method is! That allows Maven to create a manifest file (which will allow you to open the jar from terminal)

### 2. Add your JSoup dependency

Look how easy is that, no downloading, just paste that:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Wait! Remember to click on `Enable auto-import` in the down right corner! That will allow Maven to auto-download your dependencies.

### 3. Add your files

Put your `out.txt` file into `resources` folder, and your `.java` files into `src/main/java/` folder, and you're ready!

Now you can obtain your stream using

```
ClassLoader loader = YourClass.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("out.txt");
```

Keep in mind that you shouldn't write to that file, only read. If you want to write, then you should create that file elsewhere.

### 4. Building

To build your jar just open `Maven Tools` like so:
[image]

And then hit `install` command from it:

[image]

Wait a little and your jar file ready to use should be in `/target/` folder in your root project.

If you have any questions, ask them! I will help you with usage of Maven. ;)

Comment: Also, using Maven, you don't need to do something like this `java -cp src/:lib/jsoup-1.11.3.jar Main`. `maven-shade-plugin` will combine `Jsoup` into your jar, so you can just do `java -jar yourJar.jar` on every PC! That tool is really awesome, and I don't imagine living with manual library downloading :)

Comment: `classLoader.getResource("out.txt").getFile()` is **not correct.**  getFile() *does not* convert a URL to a file.  It just returns the path portion of the URL, which will be a nonexistent file name if the path happens to have any characters which are not allowed in a URL (including spaces).  The correct way to read a resource is to *avoid using the File class altogether* and Class.getResourceAsStream to read it.  Resources should never be written;  write to a known location like the user.home or a temporary file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your main class and txt file are in the same folder, so don't give path as `"src"+ fs + "out.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code hardcoded to read the out.txt from src directory and you ran the code inside src directory, obvious it cannot find another src/out.txt under the src/ directory itself.

So don't go into the src directory, stay in Task_3 directory and try this:

```
java -cp src/:lib/jsoup-1.11.3.jar Main
```